# Can't send data to or from a Galaxy Nexus through LLCP

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have a Galaxy Nexus phone with Android 4.0.2 and a NXP demoboard PN532-C106.

I am trying to connect them to send data using the LLCP protocol and I am using "npp-server" and "llcp-test-server" from libnfc-llcp to do that. But I can only get them to start the connection only to have it closed. I can't send any data and to and the logcat seams to indicates that there is something wrong in the connection setup, see the end of the post.

I have tried to find any example code for sending data and I have tried to use nfcpy (a python library for nfc communication) but it refuses to find my demoboard. And the "npp-server" example requires a file to run and I am using an empty file since I don't know what to put in it.

I don't know if there is something wrong with my setup or if I am missing something. Is there anyone who know why my connection dies so fast, or have a working example I can follow?

Here is the output from logcat
From test with npp-server

```
03-09 14:22:28.035: D/dalvikvm(196): GC_EXPLICIT freed 134K, 10% free 24179K/26759K, paused 6ms+5ms
03-09 14:22:58.723: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte 90
03-09 14:22:58.723: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte ec
03-09 14:22:58.723: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte 50
03-09 14:22:58.723: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte 0
03-09 14:22:58.723: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte 31
03-09 14:22:58.723: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte 56
03-09 14:22:59.129: D/NFC JNI(429): Discovered P2P Target
03-09 14:22:59.137: D/NfcService(429): LLCP Activation message
03-09 14:22:59.137: D/NfcService(429): NativeP2pDevice.MODE_P2P_TARGET
03-09 14:22:59.168: D/NfcService(429): Cannot connect remote Target. Polling loop restarted.
03-09 14:22:59.785: W/ThrottleService(196): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
03-09 14:23:04.481: D/dalvikvm(7375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 151K, 2% free 14308K/14535K, paused 7ms+3ms
03-09 14:23:08.535: D/NfcService(429): Set Foreground Dispatch
03-09 14:23:08.543: D/NfcService(429): Set Foreground Dispatch
03-09 14:23:08.598: V/PhoneStatusBar(271): setLightsOn(true)
03-09 14:23:08.598: I/WindowManager(196): createSurface Window{41c2a718 android.stickynotes/android.stickynotes.StickyNotesActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
03-09 14:23:20.238: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte d0
03-09 14:23:20.238: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte db
03-09 14:23:20.238: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte 52
03-09 14:23:20.238: W/NFC-LLC(429): bad LLC length byte 1
03-09 14:23:20.340: W/NFC_uart(429): timeout!
03-09 14:23:20.340: W/NFC-LLC(429): LLC length mis-match
03-09 14:23:20.637: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD ACTIVATED
03-09 14:23:20.637: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD DEACTIVATED
```

This part is from test with llcp-test-server

```
enter code here

03-09 14:23:20.653: D/NFC JNI(429): Discovered P2P Target
03-09 14:23:20.653: D/NfcService(429): LLCP Activation message
03-09 14:23:20.653: D/NfcService(429): NativeP2pDevice.MODE_P2P_TARGET
03-09 14:23:20.684: D/NfcService(429): Cannot connect remote Target. Polling loop restarted.
03-09 14:23:53.957: D/NfcService(429): Set Foreground Dispatch
03-09 14:23:53.965: D/NfcService(429): Set Foreground Dispatch
03-09 14:23:53.973: V/PhoneStatusBar(271): setLightsOn(true)
03-09 14:23:53.988: W/InputManagerService(196): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41a3b620
03-09 14:24:03.082: W/NFC_uart(429): timeout!
03-09 14:24:03.082: W/NFC-LLC(429): LLC length mis-match
03-09 14:24:03.387: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD ACTIVATED
03-09 14:24:03.387: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD DEACTIVATED
03-09 14:24:03.387: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD ACTIVATED
03-09 14:24:03.387: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD DEACTIVATED
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NFC JNI(429): Discovered P2P Initiator
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NFC JNI(429): 46 
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NFC JNI(429): 66 
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NFC JNI(429): 6d 
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NfcService(429): LLCP Activation message
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NfcService(429): NativeP2pDevice.MODE_P2P_INITIATOR
03-09 14:24:03.418: I/NFC JNI(429): LLCP Link deactivated
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NfcService(429): Target Activate LLCP OK
03-09 14:24:03.418: I/NfcP2pLinkManager(429): LLCP activated
03-09 14:24:03.418: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(429): onP2pInRange()
03-09 14:24:03.426: D/PermissionCache(116): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1025 => granted (457 us)
03-09 14:24:03.567: D/dalvikvm(429): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 174K, 5% free 14576K/15303K, paused 15ms
03-09 14:24:03.574: I/dalvikvm-heap(429): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.416MB for 3265936-byte allocation
03-09 14:24:03.621: D/dalvikvm(429): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 5% free 17761K/18503K, paused 4ms+5ms
03-09 14:24:03.660: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(429): onP2pSendConfirmationRequested()
03-09 14:24:03.668: D/NfcService(429): LLCP Link Deactivated message. Restart polling loop.
03-09 14:24:03.668: D/NfcService(429): not disconnecting from initiator
03-09 14:24:03.668: I/NfcP2pLinkManager(429): LLCP deactivated.
03-09 14:24:03.668: D/PhoneStatusBar(271): disable: < EXPAND* icons alerts ticker system_info back home recent clock >
03-09 14:24:03.676: I/WindowManager(196): createSurface Window{41bde010  paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
03-09 14:24:03.684: D/libEGL(429): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
03-09 14:24:03.699: D/libEGL(429): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-09 14:24:03.707: D/libEGL(429): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-09 14:24:03.715: D/libEGL(429): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-09 14:24:03.817: D/OpenGLRenderer(429): Enabling debug mode 0
03-09 14:24:03.824: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7375): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-09 14:24:03.824: W/InputManagerService(196): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41b90588 (uid=10090 pid=7375)
03-09 14:24:04.426: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(429): Debounce timeout
03-09 14:24:04.426: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(429): onP2pOutOfRange()
03-09 14:24:04.754: D/PhoneStatusBar(271): disable: < expand* icons alerts ticker system_info back home recent clock >
03-09 14:24:04.801: W/SurfaceTexture(429): freeAllBuffersExceptCurrentLocked called but mQueue is not empty
03-09 14:24:07.676: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD ACTIVATED
03-09 14:24:07.699: D/NfcService(429): SE FIELD DEACTIVATED`
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this project by Arduino + PM532. I used the PN532 library at GitHub. Using it, I could send text and image from PM532 to the Android phone. You can use this library (https://github.com/don/NDEF).

Comment: While this tool or library may help answer the question, [you should at least explain more why it does so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).